# ReactNative: Is there a way to access the calculation done by {width: auto}

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm pretty sure the answer is "no", but I feel like there has to be some way to do this.

React does some calculation behind the scenes to figure out what size your component *wants* to be based on its contents (i.e. if you set `width: auto` on the component). I would like access to that calculation or the result.

Is there any way to do this?

So far, digging through the documentation as well as the `node-modules\react-native` has turned up nothing.

EDIT: I now have a workaround, but it's ugly and calculation-intensive, so if anyone figures out how to get those numbers, I'd love to see it. I get the answers that say you can't, but the calculation has to be happening somewhere, and I don't see why we can't use the same code they do.

Comment: Idk if it can be useful, but you can access the width value after the first render with the `onLayout` prop assigned to your component view: `<View onLayout={event => { const {x, y, width, height} = event.nativeEvent.layout; }} />`

Comment: That might work. I'll run some tests tonight. If I can get that so it only updates when the children of that view change instead of every layout event, I can just store that as `desiredWidth` or something.

Comment: Oh, I misread your comment. I thought there was a way to do it only once. There exists some width, that doesn't change unless the component changes, which represents the width the component would be if it got as much space as it wants. That's the number I'm looking for, not its size on render. Basically a generalized version of `react-native-measure-text`.

Comment: Okay, I might have a workaround, but it's kind of madness. If I put the `Table` in an arbitrarily large `ScrollView`, then everything stretches out to be as big as it wants. I can measure that size and then use that for my desired dimensions, calculate the dimensions I'm actually going to use, and then display everything at the size I want it to be in a normal `View`.

Comment: Yeah, the workaround seems fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this is for the next person who's looking for this.

The reason all the other answers on the related questions say "no" is because you can't do it purely through React, because React isn't the one doing that calculation. It's all handled on the native side.

So, if you're SURE your thing won't work without access to that calculation, you have to build a native module, and then each platform will give you access to some kind of `measure()` function.

But make sure you really can't do what you're trying any other way, because it's gonna be A LOT more work.